# ASM at&t syntax

Tags: c++, unix, assembly

so i've a problem with this code. This is a program for converting from binary to deximal numbers.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

char s[100];
    int length;
    int a;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n  Vvedite stroky iz 0 i 1 (do 8 delementov) > ");
    gets(s);

    asm("leal s,%esi");
    asm("movl 8,%ecx");
    asm("movl 0,%edx");
    asm("repeat:");
    asm("movl 1,%eax");
    asm("dec %ecx");
    asm("rol %cl,%eax");
    asm("cmpb 31,%esi");
    asm("jnz x");
    asm("add %eax,%edx");
    asm("x: inc %esi");
    asm("cmpb 0,$esi");
    asm("jnz repeat");
    asm("movl %edx,a");

    printf("4islo %d",a);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It gives me:
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Please help with this ASM part.
I think the problem in the CMPB operator.

Comment: I personally avoid AT&T syntax, but shouldn't you be prefixing all immediates with `$` and all registers with `%` ?  (for example, the line `cmpb 0,$esi` ought to be `cmpb $0,%esi`).

Comment: It doesn't look to me like this code is really very close to doing the  job at all. Until you're fairly accustomed to writing assembly language, it's often easiest to write some working code in something like c, *then* write code that does (roughly) the same thing in assembly language.

Comment: Each `asm` statement is independent. You cannot assume the registers hold the values you assume either before or after each `asm` block. You might want to read a [*good* tutorial](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/) on GCC inline assembly.

Comment: @BrettHale Do you have an example when this could happen? From the docs, I understand that each `asm` statement´s text is copied into the assembly verbatim, so when would the compiler choose to insert additional instructions inbetween two immediately successive `asm` statements?

Comment: @Andreas - There are no outputs, inputs, or clobbered operands. From the compiler's perspective, they have no effect. The loophole here is that: `"An asm instruction without any output operands is treated identically to a volatile asm instruction."`, which only guarantees that the `asm` statements are not optimized away. The compiler is free to insert instructions between them - whether this happens in practice is not specified, and therefore can't be relied on. (cont...)

Comment: @Andreas ...  From the same [section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) : `"... you can't expect a sequence of volatile asm instructions to remain perfectly consecutive. If you want consecutive output, use a single asm. Also, GCC performs some optimizations across a volatile asm instruction ... "`

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with that code - on my system, it did not even run through the compiler/assembler. The main issue is that you need to prefix all literals with `$`, otherwise the assembler assumes a memory access:

```
asm("movl 8,%ecx"); // tries to access memory at address 8 => Segmentation fault
```

This needs to be

```
asm("movl $8,%ecx"); // Moves literal 8 into ecx
```

Adjust all other instructions accordingly.

Another issue is the following instruction:

```
asm("cmpb 0,$esi");   // $esi is not a literal nor a register name
```

This needs to be

```
asm("cmpb $0,(%esi)");  // compare value at address stored in %esi with literal 0 (end of string)
```

I suggest that you compile the code with debug information, like

```
$ g++ -g -o sample sample.c
```

It is then quite easy to debug the program:

```
$ gdb sample 
(gdb) run
Starting program: sample 
sh: cls: command not found

   Vvedite stroky iz 0 i 1 (do 8 delementov) > 10101010

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe238) at sample.c:18
18          asm("movl 8,%ecx");   // current bit position
```

As you can see, the debugger shows you the instruction which caused the segmentation fault.

**Update**

The assembly code which worked for me, using a single `asm` statement as suggested by @Brett:

```
asm("leal s, %esi         \n\t"   // s => %esi
    "movl $8, %ecx        \n\t"   // current bit position (+1)
    "movl $0, %edx        \n"     // initialize result

"repeat:                  \n\t"
    "movl $1, %eax        \n\t"   // Create bit mask in %eax
    "dec  %ecx            \n\t"   // Decrement rotation counter to shift mask bit to proper position
    "rol  %cl, %eax       \n\t"   // calculate value of current binary digit

    "cmpb $0x31, (%esi)   \n\t"   // current digit == 1?
    "jnz  x               \n\t"   // no, skip
    "add  %eax, %edx      \n"     // add current value to %edx

 "x:                      \n\t"
    "inc  %esi            \n\t"   // next address in input string
    "cmpb $0, (%esi)      \n\t"   // end of string reached?
    "jnz  repeat          \n\t"   // no, continue

    "movl %edx,a          \n");   // store result in a variable
```

```
$ ./sample 

  Vvedite stroky iz 0 i 1 (do 8 delementov) > 10101010
4islo 170
```

Comment: I changed this code and it compiles, but it gives a zero
asm("leal s,%esi");
 asm("movl $8,%ecx");
 asm("movl $0,%edx");
 asm("repeat:");
 asm("movl $1,%eax");
 asm("dec %ecx");
 asm("rol %cl,%eax");
 asm("cmpl $31,%esi");
 asm("jnz x");
 asm("add %eax,%edx");
 asm("x:"); 
 asm("incl %esi");
 asm("cmpl $0,%esi");
 asm("jnz repeat");
 asm("movl %edx,a");

 printf("4islo %d \n",a);

Comment: `cmpl $31,%esi` needs to be `cmpb $31,(%esi)` (indirect addressing), and the same for `cmpl $0,%esi`, this needs to be `cmpb $0,(%esi)`

Comment: Note that `$31` also needs to be `$0x31` (hex value `0x31` is ASCII "1", not decimal value `31`)