# GCC Segmentation fault with -O1 and inline assembler

Tags: linux, debugging, ubuntu, gcc, inline-assembly

I have detected a strange segmentation fault in my code and I would like to hear your opinion if that could be a GCC bug or is just my fault!

The function looks like that:

```
void testMMX( ... ) {
unsigned long a         = ...;
unsigned char const* b = ...;
unsigned long c    = ...;
__asm__ volatile ( 
    "pusha;" 
);
__asm__ volatile ( "mov %0, %%eax;" : : "m"( a ) : "%eax" ); // with "r"( a ) it just works fine!
__asm__ volatile ( "add %0, %%eax;" : : "m"( b ) : "%eax" );
__asm__ volatile ( "mov %0, %%esi;" : : "m"( c ) : "%eax", "%esi" );
__asm__ volatile (
    "sub %eax, %esi;"
    "dec %esi;"
    "movd (%esi), %mm0;"
    "popa;" 
);
}
```

If I compile this with -O0 it just works fine. But it SegFaults with -O1 and -O2. It took me a long time to figure out that this segfault was caused by frame pointer omission. The pusha instruction increases the stack size by 4*8=32 byte (x86_32) and therefore ESP should be increases as well. But gcc does not recognize this. If I add the ESP fix manually

```
__asm__("add $32, %esp")
```

or use the "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" flag in gcc I can compile and run it with -O1 and -O2 without any errors!

So my question now is: why does gcc not adjust the ESP with *any* push/pop inline assembler operations if frame-pointer-omission is enabled? Is this a gcc bug? Is gcc even capable of detecting this? Am I missing something?

It would be very interesting to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing to do to solve this is to _fix your usage of inline assembly_. I don't usually rant, but the margin of a comment is too short to contain all the errors here ... First, you're using multiple `asm()` statements that _depend on each other_. Second, the way you specify your variables/operands/constraints is incorrect because neither dependencies nor clobbers are expressed correctly. Third, manipulating `SP` across _multiple inline asm_ blocks creates incorrect code (were you to declare the clobber the compiler would refuse...). Direct named reg usage is discouraged. Could go on ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - gcc is *not* capable of detecting this. It doesn't perform any analysis of the instructions that appear in the `asm` block. It is your responsibility to inform the compiler of any side effects. Can you explain what test you are performing?

Also, you should consider using a single `asm` block for this code; `volatile` may prevent reordering of the `asm` blocks, but you [cannot assume this yields consecutive instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000054/asm-att-syntax#comment31592921_21000054).

Comment: I basically just started `asm` with `gcc`, but I can say that there is probably a missed opportunity for optimization and abstraction here. The field that is usually devoted to the `clobbered registers` declares the use of an explicit register, this makes the code less "portable" or "flexible"; there is also no output in the extended asm nor a clear flow of the program because of this "strange" declarations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code above is just an example. The project I am working with has huge parts of inline assembler and I needed to understand where the SegFault comes from and exclude that this error will be fixed in upcoming gcc versions. That's all I needed to know. Inline assembly blocks will now be written more carefully ;)

Comment: @japedo - If you haven't come across it yet, you might find [this](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/) useful.

Comment: "Should consider" is far too soft a statement for the code shown. "Absolutely must change to ..." were much more appropriate.

Comment: @japedo condolences for having to work with such a codebase. This isn't a gcc bug/error, but a significant misunderstanding by the original authors of this code how gcc inline assembly works. In a way, this is "hand-tuned code known to with with `gcc-3.4.1_weirdselfcompiled-variant-CVStag-6fb4a71` and `-O1`". It's hard to give suggestions here, "have it rewritten by an expert" is not often something that software engineering managers (or worse, CTOs) like to hear.